# Creating User Accounts with SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm using  MVC 4 and I'm trying to added a new field to the UserProfile named AddedById (for house keeping).

Here is what I have:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    AddedByID = // to sure how to get the id because the account has not been created yet.
                });
```

Should I  just update the AddById after the account is created?

Comment: Why do you need that when you already have `Userid` with `Userprofile`?

Comment: @KomengeMwandila Because a support team could create the account for someone.

Comment: If an administrator is creating the account then that user is logged in... therefore you have the ID and can include it when you create a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because a support team could create the account for someone**.

If that the case, make sure that the `AddedByID` is `Nullable`, then have the `Support Team` be authenticated first before they create a `User`.

Then, make your `Register Action` look like this;

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            using (EfDb db = new EfDb())
            {                                     
                try
                {
                    var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                                ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                            model.UserName,
                            model.Password,
                                new
                                    {
                                        FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                        LastName = model.LastName,
                                        AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                        AddedByID = userProfile.UserId
                                    }
                            );

                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you have here but what about when the user create their own account? Would it be best to use an transaction that creates the user and updated the AddById field?

Comment: @hbrock  I suggested making `AddedById` `Nullable` so that when the owner of the account is the one that creates it, `AddedById` is `Null` and this should be indication enough as to whom, created the account. Also, you avoid unnecessary trip back to the database.